# Возвращаемое значение - делегат, к которому нельзя присвоить значение

Tags: c#

В статичном классе храню коллекцию: `private static Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Action<string>>> listToRaise`.

Там-же есть метод, с помощью которого я добавляю значения в эту коллекцию:

```
public static Action<string> AddNameToRaise(string group, string propertyName) {
    if (!listToRaise.ContainsKey(group))
        listToRaise.Add(group, new Dictionary<string, Action<string>>());
    Action<string> target = null;
    listToRaise[group].Add(propertyName, target);
    return listToRaise[group][propertyName];
}
```

Вызываю этот метод в основном коде следующим образом: `SingleSelectionGroup.AddNameToRaise("MyGroup", "SelectedItem")`. Так как метод возвращает `Action<string>`, то можно этому делегату присвоить значение подобным образом - `SingleSelectionGroup.AddNameToRaise("MyGroup", "SelectedItem") = s => {Наш код};`

Однако после этого возникает ошибка - `Левая часть выражения присваивания должна быть переменной, свойством или индексатором.`

Почему так происходит и как это исправить?

Comment: _Так как метод возвращает Action<string>, то можно этому делегату присвоить значение подобным образом_ - это откуда такое предположение?

Comment: `SingleSelectionGroup.AddNameToRaise("MyGroup", "SelectedItem") = s => {Наш код};` - как вы себе представляете, что методу присваивается лямда-выражение? Вызов метода всегда должен быть справа от знака `=` в выражениях присваивания. Слева должна быть переменная-приемник (как и написано в описании ошибки). Ваш метод возвращает *значение* Action<string>. Так что даже если такого рода присваивания работали бы в C#, оно бы не сработало так, как вы ожидаете.

Comment: Да, точно. Я просто забыл об этом и думал, что произвожу операцию не над методом, а над `Action<string>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что-бы обойти это нужно модифицировать метод следующим образом:

```
public static void AddPropertyNameToRaise(string group, string propertyName, Action<string> action = null) {
    if (!listToRaise.ContainsKey(group))
        listToRaise.Add(group, new Dictionary<string, Action<string>>());
    listToRaise[group].Add(propertyName, new Action<string>(action));
}
```

И вызывать его соответственно вот так: `SingleSelectionGroup.AddPropertyNameToRaise("Modpacks", "SelectedModpack", a => {...});`

Comment: Имхо, метод должен возвращать `void`. Незачем возвращать action, который и так известен. И добавлять нужно просто: `listToRaise[group].Add(propertyName, action);` Не?

Comment: Ещё мысль: может проще сделать `listToRaise` типа `Dictionary<string, Action<string>>` и добавлять по составному ключу `"Modpacks.SelectedModpack"` - то есть конкатенировать две строки.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov разные строки в сумме могут дать оджинаковый результат, потому просто конкатерировать наверное не стоит. Максимум какой нить Tuple использовать